# Deleting from SQL lite DB using Node.js/Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

I am trying to build a simple forum that will allow me to add a user to my sql liteDB and then also delete said user.

In my routes folder (Users.js) I have the necessary code to add a user which is working:

```
router.post("/add-user", (req, res, next) => {
    // Define the query
    query = "INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES( ? );"
    query_parameters = [req.body.user_name]
    
    // Execute the query and send a confirmation message
    global.db.run(query, query_parameters,
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                next(err); //send the error on to the error handler
            } else {
                res.send(`New data inserted @ id ${this.lastID}!`);
                next();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Then on the views (add-user.ejs) file I have the forum to add users (Again this works):

```
    <h1>Add User</h1>
    <form action="add-user" method="post">
        <p>User: <input id="user" type="text" name="user_name" /></p>
        <button type="submit">Create a new user record</button>
```

Now I want to setup a similar interaction which will allow me to delete a user from the same DB. On my add-user.ejs file I am trying to use an override method as well to get this working  :

```
    <h1>Remove User</h1>
    <form method='post' action="add-user?_method=DELETE">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <p>User: <input id="id" type="text" name="user_id" /></p>
        <button type="submit">Remove user</button>
    </form>
```

And this is what I have in routes:

```
router.delete("/add-users", (req, res, next) => {
    // Define the query
    query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name = ( ? );"
    query_parameters = [req.body.user_name]

    // Execute the query and send a confirmation message
    global.db.run(query, query_parameters,
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                next(err); //send the error on to the error handler
                console.log(req.body.user_name);
            } else {
                res.send(`User deleted ${this.lastID}!`);
                next();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

It is a fairly simple DB Schema:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
user_name TEXT
);

When I run this I just see an error in the browser:

"Cannot POST /users/add-user"

I also see the URL changes to:

http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/add-user?_method=DELETE

I have tried playing around with different _method=DELETE code however, I cannot seem to get this to read the Delete.

I am not sure what exactly is the difference in my code for adding/removing users since the add works just fine and for delete I am overriding the method as expected.

Comment: You can use [method-override](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html) so that you can use your `router.delete` methods. HTML forms only support `POST` and `GET`. Alternatively, you can handle the form as a regular `POST` but specify delete in the url such `action="delete-user"` and then on your server `router.post("/delete-user"`